# Inno Setup: Display desktop shortcut on Finish Page

Tags: inno-setup

We are showing restart options on finish page as restart is required after our product installation. If we show restart options on finish page we are unable to display checkbox on finish page. Is there a way to show both restart options and checkbox on finish page.

Comment: What is the *shortcut checkbox* ? Do you mean the check box that lets the user run some application after finishing the setup ? If so, what should happen if the user decides to keep it checked and selects the restart option ? Would the application start and immediately terminate when the system shuts down ? These options should be mutually exclusive. Either the user decides to restart the system with no *run the app.* option, or decides to not restart and only in that case offer the *run the app.* option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. You have to basically implement your own set of checkboxes, and handle them on your own.

I'm doing the same in my installer. See [my .iss](https://github.com/winscp/winscp/blob/5.12.2/deployment/winscpsetup.iss). The Numbers in the list below point to respective lines in my code.

- In `InitializeWizard` create a set of checkboxes on `WizardForm.FinishedPage`. [#1144](https://github.com/winscp/winscp/blob/5.12.2/deployment/winscpsetup.iss#L1144)
- Implement event handler for `WizardForm.YesRadio.OnClick` and `WizardForm.NoRadio.OnClick` to disable (enable) the checkboxes when user opts to restart (or not restart). As @TLama pointed out, it does not make sense to execute something, if user is going to restart the machine. [#621](https://github.com/winscp/winscp/blob/5.12.2/deployment/winscpsetup.iss#L621) [#1212](https://github.com/winscp/winscp/blob/5.12.2/deployment/winscpsetup.iss#L1212)
- In `CurPageChanged` for `CurPageID = wpFinished`, place the checkboxes below `WizardForm.FinishedLabel`, if restarting is not needed; or below `WizardForm.NoRadio.Top`, if restarting is needed (if restarting is needed always, you do not need this dynamic placement). [#1295](https://github.com/winscp/winscp/blob/5.12.2/deployment/winscpsetup.iss#L1295)
- In `CurStepChanged` for `CurPageID = wpDone`, process the actions according to checkboxes, if user opted not to restart. [#1443](https://github.com/winscp/winscp/blob/5.12.2/deployment/winscpsetup.iss#L1443)

Answer (score -1):

you can do this using NeedRestart() method, as describe in following code. just set flag boolean flag ResultForRestart to true if restart required or make it false as follows

```html
ResultForRestart: Boolean; // globel in code section

function NeedRestart(): Boolean;
begin
      Result := ResultForRestart;
end;



set flag ResultForRestart true/false as you requirement it will add two radio button restart now or latter
```

Comment: This won't change anything. Once the restart is planned, the control with run check boxes is hidden from the final page. P.S. please spend some time and learn how to format posts. Runnable code snippets are only for HTML/CSS/JavaScript based posts.